# The Advantages Of ActionBar/ABS?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have always used actionbarsherlock in my projects as it seems to be a good way to use the existing actionbar and make it compatible with older versions.

However recently a developer I am working with decided that the library is too restrictive and has made a custom view which imitates the actionbar.

It does seem to be a lot simipler than trying to figure out how to use the library. Also the way to style actionbarsherlock seems messy as you must define the style twice, further more you have to extend from ABS activities/fragments, which can be a pain when you must also extend from things like roboguice activites etc.

So what are the main advantages of using this library? It seems that it more simple, easier an less time consuming to create a custom view

Comment: first : I wonder how your app threats the space available on the device, and knows when to display items in the bar, or in the overflow for example.

Comment: how do you place a `SearchView`, that expands and then collapses `onBackPress`?

Comment: so your answer would be that it handles scaling and the animation of the search view?

Comment: this is one of the MANY MANY thing it does.

Comment: it is really a bit childish to ask this question, and I can assure you that you'll be sorry for implementing your own AB, and later you'll probably switch it to the native AB.

Comment: Please stop trolling. I asked the question to get more knowledge. I did not implement this myself as I said I ALWAYS use it. I was looking for a concrete answer not "MANY MANY"

Comment: If you would like to write an answer with the advantages I will happily mark it as correct